# Links List like news list or news ticker

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to put in my site something like news **list** or news **ticker**, but **for links**.
I've to put into this list/ticker link to my friends site; I need to open my friends sites and not to show a page containing the link.

I need something like a "Suggested links:" widget/plugin on the right or left of the page.

I don't know (I've googled a lot) if there is a plugin for this.

Can you suggest me a plugin or something else?

Thanks

Comment: You need a widget to put text links in it, am I right?

Comment: @MichalS Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:
go to dashboard -> Apperance -> Widgets and add "TEXT" widget, place your links manually

```
 <ul>
 <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a></li>
 </ul>
```

another option is to store them as post of specific category and build a widget process them, but it will make life complicated.

Comment: try it now, should be ok

Comment: Ok, now it's working, thank you. Now I'm testing a widget called Custom Link Widget [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-link-widget/)

Answer (score 0):

you have a native plugin for that :
-> http://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/links-widget/

Comment: Is this only for Wordpress.COM? I'm using wordpress.ORG. Where can I download this plugin? I've searched in wordpress.ORG without results.